# One sample median test: Wilcoxon, sign test or chi squared

Tags: hypothesis-testing, median

I would like to understand the differences between these tests for one sample median test and when to use each of them.

I have been searching information and this is what I got so far:

- Sign test (in R sign.test) does not need a probability distribution symmetric but Wilcoxon (wilcox.test) does.
- Wilcoxon is more powerful.

To check the symmetry in the prob distribution, I through an histogram right? 
What are the assumptions for each of them? When should I use them?

I am pretty lost here so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- One-sample sign test tests that the **median** in the population equals the value.
- One-sample Wilcoxon test tests that the distribution in the population **is symmetric around the value**. More technically, that the *sum* of two randomly chosen deviations from the value has equal probability to occure positive or negative. Note that rejecting this null hypothesis does *not* preclude the value to be the mean or median of the population. The rejection implies two possible reasons: either the distribution is symmetric about some other value or the distribution is not symmetric at all.
- So if we *do assume* symmetric shape of the population distribution then the Wilcoxon tests that the **mean (=median)** in the population equals the value (it is this test then is the nonparametric alternative to one-sample t-test which assumes normality). If you assume the symmetry and hence you test for mean (=median), then Wilcoxon is more powerful, as a median test, then the more universal sign test above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It is very helpful. One more question: what happens if I use Wilcoxon with a non symmetric distribution?

Comment: If the population distribution is _believed to be_ asymmetric then there can be no value around which it is symmetric, and one-sample Wilcoxon is useless.